# Remove class if other element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the currently active `li` element get some proper styling on click , and remove it when the other `li`'s element are clicked,

I am relying on this to do it :

```
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

as you can see the code works when on jsFiddle, [example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tGW3D/2/), except that it does not work for me, and I doubt that this is something has to do with Turbolinks and Jquery-turbolinks? , or is it just some css problem?

CSS file goes in this order:

```
.current /*I tried sidebar ul li.current but none happened.*/

.sidebar ul li

.sidebar ul li:hover

.sidebar ul li:active

.sidebar ul li a

a

a:hover
```

**Update #1** : Solutions I tried.

```
$('li').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('current');
        $(document).on('page:load',function(){
  $('li').addClass('current');
             });
    });
```

Not the best code in the world, this looks so wrong, however it was just a random try in vain.


This has made the changes to the whole `li`'s (obviously), after the page has loaded, that's a half solution ,except that I don't know how to get the clicked `li`.

**Update#2** : Html code structure

```
    <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-lg hidden-md" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom:0;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
      <!-- navbar -->

         <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="window">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="padding:0;">

                              <div class="span2" style="height:5%;">
                                <div class="topsidebar"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="span8" style="height:90%;">
                                <div class="sidebar">
                                             <ul>
                                                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                                                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                                                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                                                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                                                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                                                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                                            </ul>      
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="span2" style="height:5%;">
                                <div class="bottomsidebar"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <div class="span2" style="height:5%;">
                                <div class="windowtop" id="u">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="span8" style="height:90%;">
                                <div class="windowmain" style="overflow:auto;">
                                  <%= bootstrap_flash %>
                                  <%= yield %>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="span2" style="height:5%;">
                                <div class="windowbottom"></div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- window -->
            </div><!--container-fluid-->
    </body>
```

I am targeting the second `li`'s that are in the `sidebar` div.

Comment: "and this is totally functional" ... so... what's the question?

Comment: Can you show your code containing li? Also if it's a turbolinks problem then try it with `.on` something like `$(document).on("click","li",function(){your code})`

Comment: Something can't be "totally functional" and yet "not work" for you.

Comment: And would anyone explain -1?

Comment: @Mandeep Tried it, none happened.

Comment: Erm... in your update, why are you doing `$(document).ready()` *inside* of a click event handler?

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA your html code? And in the solutions your have tried your js is wrong. Also you haven't used `.on` method

Comment: I already tried `click` event as @mandeep mentioned however , I used `ready`, since `click` event will work and then the page will refresh and everything is gone.

Comment: `ready` is something you wrap *all* your js in, it's not something you intersperse into the middle of an event handler.  That simply tells the JS to wait until the page is done loading before executing the JS.  And if you're using turbolinks that will only work on a hard refresh, if you access the page via a link then you need to use `$(document).on('page:change', function(){})` or ready *and* `page:change`

Comment: @nzifnab you're right, page:change is working, however now I'm unable to access the clicked `li`, how can I do it? since `$(this)` is not doing it because it's no longer in the `$(li)` scope. Ofcourse I am using the solution I added in the update.

Comment: Did you try my answer's code with `page:change` as the event?  The code in your update looks very wrong, with that `$(document).on` inside of a click handler...

Comment: I copy pasted your answer, it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).on("click",".sidebar li",function(){
  if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
    $("li.current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
  }
});
```

*This will check if your clicked li has current class or not and **if it doesn't then only fire other statements***

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PbZR9/1/, the part about checking and removing, just sexy and working, except that not the way you stated it, it worked when `$('li'),click` only :s

Comment: yup, you're right. I rechecked, except that it does not work in my app. 

I am placing it in the script tags after the body tags, will it do any harm? (PS : *I placed an `alert`, the event gets fired and outputs the msg, except that after the msg, the page seem to refresh and no `current` class added*)

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA what is the jquery version in your app? on event was added in jquery 1.7 also put your js in application.js or make a new js file and require it in application.js. Also here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PbZR9/2/)

Comment: `jquery-rails-3.1.1`, I am relying on `on` events in other parts of the side and its working. I put the code in a file and included in application.js, none happened.

Comment: saved your code into a file named `current.js`, went to application js, in between `//= require jquery-turbolinks` and `//= require turbolinks`, I added `//= require current`.

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA Although it shouldn't matter but i have updated my code to target sidebar lis. You want active class on li or anchor tag inside li?

Comment: On `li` anchor, I was thinking that your first code should work for any li that's clicked, right? doesn't matter really where.

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA i was talking in the sense of "not working". In earlier case it should have worked on either of the lis. Do you have javascript_include_tag in your layout file?

Comment: I dunno why in the world wouldn't work , you technically gave the best answer, I'll take it as a solution and figure out if the problem lays somewhere else... 

Thanks for the vast time!

Comment: Yes I do, in the top at `head` tags. Everything is set quite properly, all js files work , except for this. , `alerts` fires when put inside of the code you provided, but the `current`class doesn't get added, lol...

Comment: Yup!, actually i added two of them with differnet content, the `click` is working, and the `if` works! , dunno why the hell nothing appears, ichecked the style.. everything's good.

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA If alert works then everything else should also work. Inspect your elements after you have clicked on an li and see if it has the class or not?

Comment: Haha, Guess what , I added `alert` at the end of `if` all of a sudden it works! and then it does not for another two buttons, and then it does! I suppose there is some other file making this conflict? I have some loading indicator being added, and other files, will this affect it in any way?

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA i think you have multiple js firing for the same event

Comment: Not really, I see what's happening, it does not work when I click on a button that launches uses `page:load` and `ready`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58516/discussion-between-techpushta-and-mandeep).

Answer (score 0):

With turbolinks active you need to bind your event handlers on a different event than `$(document).ready(...)`:

```
$(document).on 'page:change', ->
  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
  });
}
```

See turbolinks documentation for other page lifecycle events here: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

Comment: Not working, I actually made something like this before asking, i'll put it and please update your question if it helps you make a better one.

Comment: Are your `li` elements available on page load or are they being added after the page has been loaded?  If it works in the jsfiddle then there's something else going on here.

Comment: Better yet, are you inspecting the element with your browser's inspector tool to see if the class is being added?  If it's a CSS issue, inspecting the element will let you know.

Comment: I am inspecting, however there are no error messages.
`li` elements will be rendered after the page load normally, except that turbolinks will let them static and refresh only the yield part, am I wrong about turbolinks?

Comment: Not sure I followed that sentence. If you do a hard refresh on the page (which means turbolinks isn't going to do anything) - are the `li` links there on the page immediately, or does some JS, ajax, or remote rails calls add them to the page shortly afterwards?

Comment: Ah , I'm sorry, I am the one to not understand your question, Yes, they are there directly added, immediatly.